# How to mock mongoose model dependency using jest

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

So I'm trying to test a mongoose model with a dependency of another model, but I got an error telling me `Target class "undefined" passed in to the "DefinitionsFactory#createForClass()" method is "undefined".`:

Here is my schema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from '~/user/schemas';

export type JustificationDocument = Justification & Document;

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Justification {
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  user: User;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  sku: string;

  @Prop()
  text: string;

  @Prop()
  combatantSku?: string;

  @Prop()
  combatantSkuLink?: string;
}

export const JustificationSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Justification);

    enter code here
```

This is the full error when I try to mock mongoose with `jest.mock('mongoose');`:
[error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0pfX.png)

Comment: Mongoose has a large, complex API that you don't own; I would recommend _not_ mocking it.

Comment: The closest I would get to mocking mongoose is [mocking the model instance that gets injected into your service](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/tree/main/apps/mongo-sample) and even then I'd suggest a helper tool like `@golevelup/ts-jest` to create the mock for you

Answer (score 1):

i suffered from this error almost 4 day.
but i have just solved this problem.
it occurs from '@Prop()' decorator because '@nestjs/mongoose' is not mocked.  you should mock '@nestjs/mongoose' and mocked @Prop should return object.

```
jest.mock('mongoose');
jest.mock('@nestjs/mongoose', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@nestjs/mongoose');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    Prop: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => {}),
  };
});
```

i don't know whether you solved or not, but i hope my comment helps you.